# spring boot loop in @async mulit-thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

If I give the index value when I call doSomething(), the index value is 100. How to solve it?
I want the index to be 0,1,2,3,4

```
List<CompletableFuture> futures = new ArrayList();for(
int i = 0;i<100;i++)
{
    futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doSomething(i)));
    futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doSomethingElse(i)));
}CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).thenRunAsync(()->log("Ended doing things"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable `i` must be `final` or `effectively final`. You can use somethink like `AtomicInteger` or make copy of it e.g.

```java
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int finalI = i;
    futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doSomething(finalI)));
    futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doSomethingElse(finalI)));
}
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).thenRunAsync(() -> log("Ended doing things"));
```

Comment: I guess this is because you are passing references and thus end up with `i = 100;` when `doSomething(i);` finally fires? (given the original question code)

Comment: An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing scope that are not declared as final or effectively final [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). Lambda is nothing else but anonymous class.

Comment: It is multithreaded, so you basically do not know, when it executes and what value will be stored inside `i`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It was what I guess it would do, but nice to have somebody with more knowledge confirm it.